# Which method of current fragment is called when a new fragment is added in same activity

Tags: android, android-fragments

I want to hide error message of edit text, when new fragment is added on top of current fragment, But no method of current fragment is called when new fragment is added on top, in same activity.

Thanks.

I just want to hide error message of EditText view added on fragmentA as given below.

```
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.um_fragment_nav_signup_frag, container, false);

    mobileNumEditText= (EditText) view.findViewById(R.id.et_nav_mobile);

    mobileNumEditText.setOnFocusChangeListener(new View.OnFocusChangeListener() {
        @Override
        public void onFocusChange(View v, boolean hasFocus) {
            mobileNumEditText.setError(null);
        }
    });

    return view;
}

@Override
public void onHiddenChanged(boolean hidden) {
    mobileNumEditText.setError(null);
    super.onHiddenChanged(hidden);
}

@Override
public void onPause() {
    mobileNumEditText.setError(null);
    super.onPause();
}
```

but non of these method called while adding another fragment(FragmentB) in Same activity, with given method.

```
@Override
public final void addFragment(Fragment fragment, int containerId,
                              boolean addToBackStack) {
    FragmentTransaction ft = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
    ft.add(containerId, fragment, fragment.getClass().getSimpleName());
    if (addToBackStack) {
        ft.addToBackStack(null);
    }
    ft.commit();
}
```

Comment: It looks like you want us to write some code for you. While many users are willing to produce code for a coder in distress, they usually only help when the poster has already tried to solve the problem on their own. A good way to demonstrate this effort is to include the code you've written so far, example input (if there is any), the expected output, and the output you actually get (console output, tracebacks, etc.). The more detail you provide, the more answers you are likely to receive. Check the [FAQ] and [ask].

Comment: i edited a question, please check it now.

Comment: Why don't you use Object of existing Fragment A in addFragment method to call public method of Fragment A to remove mobileNumEditText.setError(null);

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Current Fragment will only be affected if it’s removed or replaced. Simply adding new fragment will just display new fragment over current fragment and no life cycle method of current fragment is called.

According to your issue,it is better you hide error message of edit text just before doing fragment transaction.

Check out-
 https://androidlearnersite.wordpress.com/2017/02/27/fragment-lifecycle-during-fragment-transaction/

Answer (score 0):

Please go through the [fragment lifecycle](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Fragment.html#Lifecycle) and check it out yourself.

I would suggest you to override all the fragment lifecycle methods in your fragment and place breakpoints in each and every methods and check it out for yourself.

Comment: I checked lifecycle of fragment but couldn't found any of current fragment method called when a new fragment is added.

Comment: Show the fragment code where you are overriding the methods

Answer (score 0):

If I understood correctly, you're looking for onPause() method, that is called for the fragment that has been replaced by another.

Comment: But onPause() method of fragment is not called while adding another fragment on top.